# Why doesn't smoothing work in sculpting mode?

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to smooth an object in sculpting mode using the smoothing brush, but when I click my computer just lags and nothing changes. [image]

Comment: Do you have the water object active when going into sculpt mode?

Comment: The higher the vertex count of the mesh the more blender will slow during sculpt and the less noticeable the smoothing. Also try putting the strength up to 1.0. If you zoom in close do you see the smoothing happening?

Comment: Please apply the fluid modifier first..